# How to draw current arrow entering resistor not leaving? circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How do I label the small current arrow to enter the resistor rather than leave it? I'm trying to make my diagram look like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, european resistors] \draw
(0,0) to[I, l^=\mbox{$i_s=5mA$}] (0,3) -- (1.5,3)
  to[R=2K, i_=$i_1$] (1.5,0) -- (0,0)
(1.5,3) -- (4,3)
  to[R=3K, i_=$i_2$] (4,0) -- (1.5,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Mine shows up like this:

[image]

Also, can someone help me with the $v_s$? 
I'm very new to latex, so help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, american currents, american resistors] \draw
(0,0) to[I, l^=\mbox{$i_s=5mA$}] (0,3) 
(0,0)-- (1.5,0)
  to[R=2K, i^<=$i_1$] (1.5,3) -- (0,3)
(1.5,0) -- (4,0)
  to[R=3K, i^<=$i_2$] (4,3) -- (1.5,3)
;
\node at (2.5,1.5) {$v_s$};
\node at (2.5,2.75) {$+$};
\node at (2.5,0.25) {$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

I reversed almost everything... you can do it easier if you place resistors separate from other lines.

Output:

I don't really know if breaking a circuit to parts is a good practice for circuitikz

[image]

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX... I just show your edits too... but changed almost anything and looking to correct it again. Thanks... fixing... we was editing in the same time.

Comment: Thanks... I have already fixed that (show it in your edit earlier)... I will edit again to manually add a `$v_s$` and `+/-` if someone has better circuiticz knowledge please add an answer since I think there are better ways.